# How to check if a discord embed contains a link?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am developing some software to automatically open up links posted in discord in your default browser. It works when a normal message is sent, but I need it to also check embeds for a link and open that. Any ideas?

```
    linkclient2.on("message", message => {
        if (message.channel.id == CHANNEL_ID) {
            if (message.content.includes('https')) {
                var link = message.content.split('https')[1]
                console.log(link)
                var linktest = `https${link}`
                console.log(`opening ${linktest}`)
                open(linktest)
                
            }
             // check if an embed contains 'https'
            
              
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gets all the embeds in the message and checks if any of the descriptions are links:

```js
// check if an embed contains 'https'
else if (message.embeds) {
  message.embeds.forEach(embed => {
    if (embed.description.includes('https')) {
      const link = embed.description.split('https')[1];
      console.log(link);
      const linktest = `https${link}`;
      console.log(`opening ${linktest}`);
      open(linktest);
    }
  });
}
```